# Python Automation "For" "In" statements

Tags: python, for-loop

I've been studying python for a while now and I really cant wrap my head around the `for .. in` statements. I have a slight idea of what they mean but not completely sure.

So my friend gave me this code to work with

```
print("My name is")
for i in range (5):
    print("Jimmy Five Time" + str(i))
```

And from my understanding (For loops will loop a specific number of times)
and the range function is the range of the number line which in this case is 0-5

What I need help with is to explain what are the `for` and `in` statements do. I want to completely understand what I'm working with. I've googled for examples and whatnot but I really can't seem to get the hang of it.

Comment: Have you tried *running* that code? Modifying it to see what happens when you change things? Reading the documentation/a tutorial? Your understanding seems reasonably accurate (note that, in Python, 0-5 *doesn't include five*), so it's not at all clear what you still want to know.

Comment: Im not sure that I expressed myself good enough, I've been working with the statements for about 2 weeks & I need someone to explain what they "mean" not how they "work" I know what they do but I dont understand it.

Comment: ...what?! No, I'm certain that you haven't expressed yourself well. There are (so many!) introductory tutorials out there already, we're not here to try to write you another one without even getting a clear problem statement.

Comment: Also, English is not my first language so I apologize for my bad grammar.

Comment: Python has extensive documentation, too; see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement and https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in

Comment: The only thing I could suggest is to abandon the way you're learning python and start over. Probably http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ could be of great value to you, since it starts with simple concepts. If you're feeling confident, loops are excercise # 32

Comment: Are you generally familiar with the concept of *loops* in programming? Is your question specific to the implementation of `for..in` in Python, or do you generally have a hard time understanding loops?

Comment: This is not a place to learn python, you can read some books

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
iterator = my_object.__iter__()
while True:
    try:
        something = iterator.next()
    except StopIteration:
        # StopIteration exception is raised after last element
        break

    # loop code
    print something
```

Comment: FYI: Stack Overflow is not a "forum" and this isn't a "thread". You're not really supposed to post an answer here to "talk to people". If you want to comment on someone's answer, write them a comment.

Comment: @deceze isn't that what I did? Except for when I answered my own question. I thought you answered your own question to show that you were done with it, that you got the help that you wanted and it's good to cancel "post"

Comment: *"I thought you answered your own question to show that you were done with it"* - no, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (indeed, spending some time in the Help Center generally would be a good idea)

Answer (score 3):

`for..in` is a way to *iterate* over an *iterable*.

That means: an *iterable* is anything that can be *iterated over*, say a list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`range()` produces just such a list, so it's a good example. Now, to *iterate over* such a list means to *take one item and do something with it*, then take the next item and do something with it, and so on until there are no more items in the list.

`for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]` means it takes `1`, assign it to `i`, then executes the indented code following this statement; then it takes `2`, assigns it to `i`, and executes the code again; and so on and so on.

```
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    print(i)
```

This first prints `1`, then `2`, then `3`, then `4`, then the list is exhausted and the iteration stops.

There are other kinds of *iterables* in Python that can be *iterated over* the same way.

Answer (score 0):

OK, range(5) creates a list from 0-4:

```
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, 'FOR' each value 'IN' the list that is created with 'range(5)' substitute 'i' for that value. Would be equivalent to writing out each print line:

```
print("Jimmy Five Time" + str(0))
print("Jimmy Five Time" + str(1))
print("Jimmy Five Time" + str(2))
print("Jimmy Five Time" + str(3))
print("Jimmy Five Time" + str(4))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Chris Montanaro, That is exactly the explanation I was looking for, Now I "UNDERSTAND" what "FOR" & "IN" does, "IN" is the Integer "Value" and "FOR" each value it adds what substitutes "i" for example.
i = cat
in = 1-5
so it adds cat to all the 5 numbers.

Comment: @HaleyAlisson no, that's not accurate

Comment: @HaleyAlisson: `range` doesn't create a list in Python 3 and you can use non-integer values too: `for value in ['A', 'B', 'XYZ']:`.

Answer (score 0):

Anything after the `in` statement is and object implementing the iteration protocol, meaning it has the **iter** method which returns an iterator object. This is another way to write a python for loop (not a way you would do it of course, but still equivilent)

```
iterator = my_object.__iter__()
while True:
    try:
        something = iterator.next()
    except StopIteration:
        # StopIteration exception is raised after last element
        break

    # loop code
    print something
```

Hopefully this gives you a better understanding of what is going on with python for loops. I agree they can be confusing after being used to C-style looping, as so much of the detail is obscured.

Comment: Better say `iterator = iter(my_object)` as `.__iter__()` is not the only way an iterator can be obtained.